# Is this a common practice to amend a claim by striking through every word in the original claim?

Tags: claims, claim-construction

1. Is this a common practice to amend a claim by striking through the entire text of the claim and introducing completely new text, instead canceling the claim and introducing a new claim. I mean no word of the original claim remains in the amended claim.
2. When claims are cancelled, for example claims 2-4 in a patent application with 7 claims, does the patent after being issued also contain the same numbering as during prosecution and the claims have numbers 1,5,6,7 and there are no claims numbered 2,3,4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not at all** common practice to cross out all of the words and replace them with other words. Just cancel the claim and add a new one at the end, using the next number. In the U.S. the original claim numbering is maintained until after allowance. As part of the process of preparation for issuing a granted patent the claims are renumbered.